# Populating field from variable in React. using css on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, user-interface

I have below form in react.

```
      const inputForm = [
                {"canHaveAnswer":true,"label":i18n.t("signature_name1_lab"),"placeholder":i18n.t("signature_name1"),"error_message":"","type":"text","types":["text","email","number"], 
                {"canHaveAnswer":true,"label":i18n.t("signature_name2_lab"),"placeholder":i18n.t("signature_name2"),"error_message":"","type":"text","types":["text","email","number"], 
                {"canHaveAnswer":true,"label":i18n.t("signature_phone_lab"),"placeholder":i18n.t("signature_phone"),"error_message":"","type":"number","types":["text","email","number"]    
 ]
```

I am using this form like below.

```
return (
            <div>
                {i18n.t("signature_heading")}
                <ReactForm
                    data={inputForm}   --here I am refering
                    answer_data={[]}
                    ref="signature_form"
                    isValidation={isCheckValidation}
                />
            </div>
        )
```

these records getting displayed one by one in row.

I have to display them in same row. I know how to apply `css` but since it is `form`, how can I apply the same?

[image]